# My Discord bot repeats the same message multiple time

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (message.channel.type === "dm") return message.channel.send("I don't work in DM's"); { if (message.author.Client) return; };
```

The bot will spam repeat "I don't work in DM's" with this code and I don't know what's wrong with it.

[Here is a picture to showcase what happens if I write a DM to the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UETtN.png)

Comment: Your logic is repeating multiple times then. Have you checked if you've already sent a message to the user?

Comment: Add `if (message.author.bot) return;` before your first if statement to stop responding to bot's messages/

Answer (score 0):

`User.Client` isn’t a property (see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User)). It is undefined, which returns falsey and does *not* return. Use [`User.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=bot) instead

```js
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
        return message.channel.send("I don't work in DM's");
    }
```

Comment: `User.bot` is a boolean for whether or not the message sender is *any bot*, use `message.author.id === discordBot.user?.id` if you want to be able to respond to everyone (includings bots) except for yourself

Comment: It is in DM though. There is no reason to check the author id, it’s a waste of time.

Comment: Bots can DM other bots though. I wasn't saying that your answer was wrong, I was adding upon it with a better solution for most cases